# Users table missing from Database

Tags: database, users, user-meta

I have a functioning WordPress site, with two users (an Administrator and an Editor).  I can log in to the WP back-end fine with either user.  I can create pages, etc.  But when I look at phpMyAdmin, the database does *not* have a **users** table.  However, it does has the **usermeta** table, displaying details for both the Administrator user and the Editor user.

If I do an SQL statement like this: `SELECT * FROM "wp_users"`, it does show the two entries for both users that have been created - just as I would expect to see if I was looking at the **users** table. (The only unexpected difference between the two entries is that the Administrator doesn't have anything in its user_activation_key field, but I am not sure if that is a problem.)

And I can edit those entries from the above SQL query against the users table.  But there still is no **users** table listed in the left hand navigation panel (where all tables should be listed).

---

## Is there anyway to repair the Database, so it will display the users table in the navigation panel?

---

I think the problem was initiated when I created a new Administrator user through the WP dashboard.  Afterward, I then deleted the original Administrator user, indicating all associated ownership should be transferred to the new Administrator user (all down through WP back-end).

Note: I have done this step in the past with another WordPress site, and I had no problems with their Database afterwards.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers.
SunnyOz

Comment: If you can query the table then it exists. Are you sure it’s not just on a second page or something? And are you certain you’re looking at the right database?

Comment: Regardless, if WordPress is working fine then it seems like the issue is that PHPMyAdmin is not showing a table, which is a PHPMyAdmin issue, not a WordPress issue.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie, I only just now saw your comment about the second page after I had already posted my answer.  You were spot on!

Comment: Thanks for the question! I just had that freaky experience as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, dear!  Never mind!

There really **IS** a wp_users table.

I just realised that there is a second page to the list.  My wp_users table was at the top of the second page of the navigation panel!

I have never had a WP site with more than one page of tables, and didn't realise it could be split into multiple pages!

I am leaving the question up here to help anyone else that may have the same problem.

Comment: Just popping on to say this literally just happened to me and I found this by searching for "missing wordpress users table", so thank you!